# Possible to develop for iOS through Titanium on Ubuntu?

Tags: ios, xcode, ubuntu, titanium

Is it possible to run Titanium Studio on Ubuntu and then run Xcode and the simulator in an OS X VM? Or, am I restricted in the sense, that I need Xcode on the machine I'm developing in Titanium on and I'd really need to do all Titanium development in the VM or sync the project directories?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically is possible, you can use a shared folder with an OSX computer or VM, consider that the time that you are going to spend going back and forward is gonna be high.
You can set all the environment on the VM OSX machine, but maybe it's gonna be slow, maybe you can use a service like http://www.macincloud.com

Comment: ... But is it necessarily going to be slow? Isn't that more of a matter of hardware and optimization? I've virtualized operating systems out of the box without issue in the past.